# Append to nested object field

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elastic-stack

I want to append my **elasticsearch** nested object while updating

```
{
  "_index": "feed",
  "_type": "feed",
  "_id": "41",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Trip to LA",
    "stats": {
      "likes": 40,
      "comments": 50,
     },
  }
}
```

here is the query

> POST feed/feed/41/_update

```
{
  "script": { 
    "source" : "ctx._source.stats.add(params.abc)",
    "params": {
      "abc": {
        "likes":1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for append in nested object

POST feed/feed/47/_update

```
{
  "script": { 
    "source" : "ctx._source.stats.likes += params.value",
    "params": {
      "value":1
    }
  }
}
```